# php mongodb update child element

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document with child elements of items like so

```
"bar" : "547244fe10f0edd3128b4567",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "1" : {
                "message" : "",
                "display" : "true",
                "type" : "text"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "2" : {
                "id" : "234234",
                "type" : "image",
                "message" : "foo",
                "display" : "true",
                "created_at" : NumberLong(1416432114)
            }
        }, 
        {
            "3" : {
                "message" : "",
                "display" : "true",
                "type" : "text"
            }
        },
```

and I'm trying to update one of the childrens value

```
$foo['items']['1']['message'] = 'hello';
$story = InfoDB::where('_id', $id)->update($foo);
```

So that

```
        "1" : {
            "message" : "",
            "display" : "true",
            "type" : "text"
        }
```

Becomes

```
        "1" : {
            "message" : "hello",
            "display" : "true",
            "type" : "text"
        }
```

But when I run the update command it deletes all the children in the document.

Do I have to update the entire document? or is there another function?

I'm using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every one of you 'items' is an item of its own an has therefore an own array index, you have to make a little adjustment to your code. So just try to replace this code

```
$foo['items']['1']['message'] = 'hello';
```

with this one

```
$foo['items'][0]['1']['message'] = 'hello';
```

This will call the first item (0) and then the specific key within the item ("1").